# How to track if sendmail is delivering emails to the 3rd party server

Tags: sendmail

I am using centOS/sendmail/PHP to shoot order confirmation emails out of our system.  By and large it works great, but lately, it's getting way less so.

I'm getting multiple reports of emails never showing up.  My strong suspicion is that this is a 3rd party issue, that our emails are getting caught by spam filters and the like, but I need to be absolutely certain of this.

I've checked /var/log/maillog, and while I see a bunch of crap (mostly spammers getting blocked from using us as a relay), I can't really see where our legit stuff is being sent properly.

Sure, I might get something like this:

```
Apr 10 14:41:18 vps1 sendmail[13977]: 33AJfIps013977: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30421, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (33AJfIIk013978 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 10 14:41:18 vps1 sendmail[13979]: 33AJfIIk013978: to=<root@vps1.myserver.com>, ctladdr=<root@vps1.myserver.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31019, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

And that seems like the proof I'm needing.  Except I don't know what any of these messages actually are.  How do I tie the message IDs (33AJfIps013977) to an actual sent email?

I need to be able to pull up logs and say "Hey, I can prove that On April 10th, we sent an email at 2:41 PM, and it was accepted by gmail's server.  If they killed it, that's on gmail."

Because right now, it's "the emails are going out, fix it!"

Thanks for your help.